# mysql DELETE with field check from another table

Tags: php, mysql

Good morning all, happy thursday morning.  I wish I could have done this by myself but since I'm not a master in MySQL statements (yet) and I got lost in this `DELETE` query, here it goes...

I have to do a simple `DELETE` query like this, (deleting a comment by its id)

```sql
DELETE FROM mya_news_comments WHERE comment_id='".$_GET['comment_id']."'";
```

but at the same time, to prevent people deleting comments throughout the website
i need to ensure that the person deleting this comment is who it is supposed to be (in our case, an artist).

I have another table `mya_news` which has among the fields `news_id`, `artist_id`
In `mya_news_comments` I also have a field called `news_id`

So I need to check that I delete the comment_id of the particular artist, not of other artist.
Basically i need to cross-check if the `news_id` field from `mya_news_comments` checks out with a field with same `news_id` from `mya_news`, and `artist_id` from `mya_news` is equal to `$_id` (which holds my `artist_id`)

I'm really stuck here. I'd be glad to give more details if needed.

Thanks.

Comment: **Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.**  You *really* should be using prepared statements, into which you pass your variables as parameters that do not get evaluated for SQL.  If you don't know what I'm talking about, or how to fix it, read the story of [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Alternatively, you should at least use `mysql_real_escape_string()`, if you ABSOLUTELY cannot use prepared statements. Everything is better what you do here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [join](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) tables in `DELETE` statements just like you can in `SELECT` statements:

```sql
DELETE mya_news_comments
FROM   mya_news_comments JOIN mya_news USING (news_id)
WHERE  mya_news_comments.comment_id = ?
   AND mya_news.artist_id = ?
```

Comment: I managed to do something way simpler from stuff I've read on Stackoverflow

Comment: @AdrianTanase: This isn't simple?  Perhaps you could link to what you've found / post as another answer so that others can learn the simpler way too?

Comment: DELETE FROM mya_news_comments WHERE comment_id='".$_GET['comment_id']."' AND EXISTS (SELECT news_id FROM mya_news WHERE artist_id = '".$_id."' AND news_id = '".$_GET['item_id']."')";


I added in the _GET data also the $_GET['item_id'] which is a news_id, or event_id depending on what i need (i got more stuff going on)

Checked with deletion and see that it's working. So it deletes if it finds the artist_id identifier, if someone tries to manually write the URI and try to delete other comment_id that doesn't belong to the account they're using, it's not being deleted.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: yes, eggyal thanks a lot, I was just typing the answer (copying from my laptop screen on my desktop here)...i'm new to the community :)

Comment: @AdrianTanase: Your proposed answer wouldn't stop a malicious user from merely changing the `comment_id` variable in the query string, but leaving the `item_id` variable pointing to a news item which they own.  The `EXISTS` subquery will succeed, and the comment will be deleted even though it is on an unrelated news item.  You must at very least ensure that the *same* `news_id` is used in the `mya_news_comments` table - this is where joins become very much easier, per my suggested answer above.

Comment: well, i will take your comment into consideration for sure, just for a clarification the $_GET['item_id'] is actually the news_id from mya_news_comments ... and if it's the same with the one from mya_news, and if artist_id checks....should do the trick. :)

Comment: @AdrianTanase: Agreed, but your proposed solution doesn't *check* that it is the `news_id` in `mya_news_comments` - try it for yourself: you can change the `comment_id` and it will delete irrespective.  You either need to add an additional criterion to your `WHERE` clause or else use the join as I originally proposed.

Comment: after studying the problem i think i'll go with eggyal solution that uses JOIN...even tho my solution works too, (the $_id is a _SESSION var, and if it fails, the EXIST equals 0, and then the user cannot delete the comment.

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE mya_news_comments
FROM   mya_news_comments
WHERE  mya_news_comments.comment_id = (SELECT [another_table].comment_id WHERE [cond])
   AND mya_news.artist_id = (SELECT [another_table].artist_id WHERE [cond]);
```

Comment: But this query won't event compile.  It references `mya_news` in the `WHERE` condition, but no such table reference exists in the query.

Comment: I don't make his homework, i just give him a way to search.
Now, he can use two different ways to code.
My solution is just a little more expressive, so more easier.

Comment: Quite apart from there being no indication that this problem is homework, I fail to see how someone could arrive at a solution to the problem given only your erroneous answer.

Comment: He must test and arrange code, he will gain experience!
Now, i need to go make a web application.
Bye!

Comment: thanks for the contribution anyways....i've learned a new trick from your line of mysql :)